# Firebase Remote-Config crash free users

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to display a "Rate Me" popup to most active users that haven't received crashes recently.

I can easily track how active an user is by using analytics and conditions, and setting a remote-config flag to true.

Is there a way to create an audience or a condition to select users without crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by creating an exclusion group in your Analytics audience that excludes users who have logged an app_exception event within a specific timeframe.

The best way to do this, assuming you're already creating an audience for the active users you want to target, is to add on the exclusion group to that audience as well to remove users who have experienced a crash recently.

See attached screenshot for an example from the Firebase console.[image: Screenshot showing audience creation with an exclusion group for crashing users]